# Sqlite hierarchy dynamically

Tags: sqlite

help me how to write this query for below output.find my table data

```
id                    cat                    sub-cat          sub-sub
1                      remarkable   
2                      bsorpti_upd  
3                      ntimicrobiasdfsdf
4                      remarkable                Dissolve
5                      macokinetics
6                      pharmacodynamics 
7                      pharmacodynamics          Antimicrobial 
8                      pharmacodynamics          Antimicrobial          peptite
9                      Test 
10                     ideas    
11                     Test                      biologically
```

I want my output as

```
column

Remarkable
         Dissolve 
bsorpti_upd
ntimicrobiasdfsdf
macokinetics
pharmacodynamics
        Antimicrobial
               peptite
Test
         biologically
ideas
```

Comment: So how is the number of spaces computed? With `random()`?

Comment: Output as below is enough
A.1
     A.2
       A.2.1
         A.2.2
B
       B.1

Comment: Please help me out

Comment: sorry for wrong data.Please help me

Comment: Iam new to sqlite .Help me to develop the query

Comment: can we do it in query with cte recursive

Comment: Please help me out

Answer (score 0):

SELECT printf('%*s',
CASE 
WHEN nullif(sub-cat,'') IS NULL 
THEN 4
WHEN NULLIF(sub-sub,'') IS NULL
THEN 8
ELSE 12
END, ' '
) || COALESCE(NULLIF(sub-sub,''),NULLIF(sub-cat,''),cat) AS COlumn
FROM indextable t
ORDER BY primaryterm,
CASE 
WHEN NULLIF(sub-cat,'') IS NULL 
THEN 4
WHEN NULLIF(sub-sub,'') IS NULL
THEN 8
ELSE 12
END,
COALESCE(NULLIF(sub-sub,''),NULLIF(sub-cat,''),cat)